# How to lazily query a collection navigation property

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When I have to following POCO

```
class Poco {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}
```

and child

```
class Child {
  public int MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

and I want to get some children if they satisfy some predicate, for example

```
Poco mypoco = getMyPoco();
IEnumerable<Child> someChildren = mypoco.Children
                                  .Where( child => child.MyProperty > 30);
```

I'm noticing that this fetches all children from the database first, and then filters on the returned list. How can I ensure that the condition is run on the database rather than in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explicit load using `Load` method, but the lazy loading needs to be disabled for temporary.

```
var context = ...; // DbContext
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

context.Entry(mypoco)
   .Collection(poco => poco.Children)
   .Query() 
   .Where(child => child.MyProperty > 30)
   .Load();
```

The filter will be done in database and loaded into `Children`.