# LINQ columns missing in associated dbml table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I manually created an association between two tables on the dbml designer for a 1:Many relationship; both tables have keys.  When I use Linq to query them, I can see the child table as a property of the parent object & I can even get the  count of child rows for that parent.  What I can't even see is any of the columns associated with the child table.  What I'm looking to do is include only those parent rows whose child rows match a certain filter criteria.

I've seen this question asked in several places on the web, but in each one the answer is that there's no primary key on one of the tables (Both of mine do).  I think the easiest explanation is a picture so here it is:

[image: dbml designer showing PalletMaster (parent), PalletJob (Child) with association and query missing child fields]

Notice that RowSequence is a property of PalletJob in the designer, but doesn't show in intellisense.
As I mentioned, I can get the row count for pallet jobs, though (pm.PalledtJobs.Count().

Thanks!

I solved the problem through the use of a DataLoadOptions object to specify the filter criteria for the child object.  I also needed to add a test in the main query to exclude parent rows that had no child rows.

```
                System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions dlo = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
            dlo.AssociateWith<PalletMaster>(p => p.PalletJobs.Where(j => j.PartNumber.StartsWith("LS")));
            db.LoadOptions = dlo;
            var query = (from pm in db.PalletMasters
                         where pm.CreatedByUser.Contains(userFilter) &&
                          pm.PalletStatus.ToString() == "A" 
                          && pm.PalletJobs.Count() > 0 
                         orderby pm.PalletID descending
                         select pm).Skip(skipValue).Take(takeValue);
```

Comment: The fix for this situation was the use of a DataLoadOptions object to specify the child conditions, but I also needed a condition in the where clause of the main query to include only parent rows that had at least one child row:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a one-to-many relationship, so you get an `ICollection<PalletJob>`, not a single one.

Comment: Thank you and that is what I'm expecting, but I realize now that I did not state my actual issue.  I thought my query would automatically join my associated tables so that I would be able to filter on values from the child-table rows as I only started to show in the intellisense part of the posted code:  && pm.PalletJobs.RowSequence > 2.  Do I need to create my own join?

Comment: From the associated collection, you get "all or nothing" when lazy loading is enabled. To filter the collection before loading it, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723902/how-to-lazily-query-a-collection-navigation-property (which is a question I asked myself recently)